# Safari iOS Form Bug (?)

Tags: javascript, ios, html, safari

I have a simple web page which works correctly in the Safari emulator and in OSX Safari, however it reloads the site on completion of a form. I am running the latest version of iOS (9.2 13C75). The page is written in html5/css3 and uses Javascript and bootstrap css. jQuery is used to dynamically load pages into a specified div. The basic web logic is:

1. load primary html page
2. onload, jquery get content page
3. select action (iosTest) from nav bar
4. jQuery get to load form
5. press complete, clears page, displays text ... or
6. press cancel, clears page, jquery get cancel message

Step 5 works, then Safari reloads original URL

Step 6 never appears to work, Safari just reloads the original URL

My question to all is "is this a known bug and are there workarounds ... or am I doing something really dumb by dynamically loading forms?"

**Primary HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>ios Mobile Safari Test</title>
    <link href="dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/ios_test.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body onload="initialSetup('html/ios_about.html','body_cell')">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" id="topNav">
      <div class="container" id="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" id="welcome" onClick="goHome('html/ios_about.html','body_cell')">ios Mobile Safari Test</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li id="iostest"><a onClick="goiosTest('html/ios_dialog.html', 'body_cell')">iosTest</a></li>
       </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="noBorder" id="SD_Main">
        <div class="container" id="leftNav"></div>
        <div class="container" id="body_cell"></div> <!-- /container -->
    </div>
    <div class="container" id="test" width="100%"></div>
    <div class="container" id="debug" width="100%"></div>
    <script src="js/jQuery/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/iosTest.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript (iosTest.js)**

```
var body_cell = "#body_cell";
function goHome(pageToLoad, target)
{initialSetup(pageToLoad, target);}
function initialSetup (pageToLoad, target)
  {
    $.when($.get(pageToLoad) ).done(function (xml_stream)
      { $("#"+target).empty();$("#"+target).append(xml_stream);});
  }
function goiosTest(pageToLoad, target)
{
  $.when($.get(pageToLoad) ).done(function (xml_stream)
     { $("#"+target).empty();$("#"+target).append(xml_stream);});
}
function ios_postDialog(comment, o_name, c_name, Create)
{
  $(body_cell).empty();
  $(body_cell).append("<h2>dialog completed</h2>");
}
function ios_cancelDialog()
{
  $.when($.get("html/ios_alt.html") ).done(function (xml_stream)
    { $(body_cell).empty();$(body_cell).append(xml_stream);});
}
```

**Form**

```
<div class = "container" id="SD_dialogBox">
<h2>SSample Dialog Box.</h2>
  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="c_name" class="col-sm-2 control-label" >Client Name:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <select id="c_name"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="o_name" class="col-sm-2 control-label" >Opportunity Name:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <select id="o_name" ></select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="comment" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Comments on Opportunity - anything that is relevant to you.</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <textarea class="form-control" id="comment" rows="5"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8">
        <button class="button-wide" id="submit" onClick="ios_postDialog('comment', 'o_name', 'c_name', 'Create')">Save this Information</button>
        <button class="button-wide" id="cancel" onClick="ios_cancelDialog()">Cancel</button>
       </div>
      </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tested in other browsers?

Comment: Challenged there. I have tested in FFox, Safari, Chrome on OSX and Windows and in the Safari iOS Simulator in xCode. Works in all those environments. VPN access to web server limits iOS access to Safari. So, no, have not tested on other browsers on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the feedback. Turns out to be an error in supporting code. Buried deep beneath, a JS function was being called which did not exist. iOS safari didn't like that and reloaded the site when that error occurred.